# How to get list of views from "mail" in Lotus Notes using .NET?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am accessing mail from Lotus notes.

And in order to access "Inbox" i am using below code:

```
_notesDatabase = _lotusNotesServerSession.GetDatabase(LotusNotesServer, "mail\\" + nsfName, false);
NotesView inbox = _notesDatabase.GetView("($Inbox)");
```

Similarly for "Drafts".

But here i am specifying name of each view in GetView method.
Which is not good coding.

I want to list these views "Inbox","Drafts" programaticaly using C#.

Can anybody give me solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is:

```
Object[] docColl = _notesDatabase.Views as Object[];

foreach (Object objView in docColl) {  
   NotesView view = objView as NotesView;
   MessageBox.Show(view.Name);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a property of the NotesDatabase class called Views that will let you access all the views in the database.  You could loop through them to access each view.

Also this [open source class called DatabaseProperties](http://www.openntf.org/Projects/codebin/codebin.nsf/0/0A43C22F85C611D686256EC1002566B5) can help you get a list of design documents, specifically the views in the database, and many more of the view's properties.

Comment: _notesDatabase = _lotusNotesServerSession.GetDatabase(LotusNotesServer, "mail\" + nsfName, false); 

after this i am using 

_notesDatabase.views();

I am new to C#.I am enable to display it's value.
Can you help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

In VB.net, the basic code to get all views (and folders) and for each, to get all included documents, would look something like this:

```
Dim s As New notesSession
Dim db As notesDatabase
Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
Dim vws As Variant
vws = db.Views
Forall v In vws
    'New View being processed
    Dim doc As notesDocument
    Set doc = v.getFirstDocument()
    While Not (doc Is Nothing)
        ' do something for each document
        ' ....
        Set doc = v.getNextDocument(doc)
    Wend
End Forall
```