# How to filter list of views from “mail” in Lotus Notes?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

In one of post:

[How to get list of views from "mail" in Lotus Notes using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357612/how-to-get-list-of-views-from-mail-in-lotus-notes-using-c)
I was asking about getting list of view.
I am getting list of views.But now i want to filter them.

As i want only Inbox,Outbox,Draft..e.tc. (containing mails).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you iterate over all views in the database (using, say, the NotesDatabase class' Views property), then once you have a handle to a NotesView object, you can use:

- the Name attribute to compare the name to the ones of interest
- the IsFolder property to check whether you have a view or a folder (Inbox is a folder, for example)
- the EntryCount property to get the number of documents in the folder/view

Alternatively, you can use the NotesDatabase class' GetView method to get a handle to each named view or folder you care about. For example (in VB):

```
...
set vw = db.GetView ("Inbox")
if (vw.entryCount > 0) then
...
end if
```