# How to get the list of views in (lotus) notes using C api

Tags: c, lotus-notes, lotus

I looked through the available C-api for notes and couldn't find any API which will give me a list  or views in the (notes)database which I've opened. I am coding in C.

Has anyone faced similar problem and knows the solution? (Any api/documentation I might have over looked?)

I have already seen the question @ [How to get list of views from "mail" in Lotus Notes using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357612/how-to-get-list-of-views-from-mail-in-lotus-notes-using-net)... unfortunately, that doesn't help me.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSFDbGetModifiedNoteTable` can be used.

```
STATUS LNPUBLIC NSFDbGetModifiedNoteTable(
DBHANDLE hDB,
WORD NoteClassMask,
TIMEDATE Since,
TIMEDATE far *retUntil,
HANDLE far *rethTable);
```

`TIMEDATE` Since should be set to the "beginning of time"
and `NoteClassMask` should be `NOTE_CLASS_VIEW`

More info can be found [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/6.0.2/api60ref.nsf/0/85255D56004D3F6385255BCB006D595B?OpenDocument)